# Linking XML with Component View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm currently struggling with what I believe should be pretty simple.
I have created a LinearLayout in an XML file that i want to link to a `CustomComponent` that extends `LinearLayout`, meaning i started backwards.

Normally i create a CustomComponent first and this creates an XML-file linked by a tag, `<my.package.CustomComponent>` (If I'm not mistaken this is the only way they are linked(?)) and i do stuff in the `onDraw()`. But in this project i do the layout throughthe XML and not the `onDraw()`.

Linking XML with activity is done by `setContentView(R.layout.customView)` but I can't really do this in a `CustomComponent` as i don't have an `onCreate()` method inherited.

sidenote: In the XML all my imagebuttons has `android:onClick=chooseButton` but for obvious reason it can't find this method...

Any ideas regarding this problem?

**EDIT**:
the two files doesn't seem to be linked because in the xml `android:onClick="chooseButton"` the IDE says: "cannot resolve symbol chooseButton"

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dial_view_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DialView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.package.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/drawingview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:onClick="chooseButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dialpad_1_blue" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="chooseButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dialpad_2_blue" 
                 ------code repeated below-----/>
```

CustomView:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    private String mExampleString;
    private int mExampleColor = Color.RED;
    private float mExampleDimension = 0;
    private Drawable mExampleDrawable;
    private TextPaint mTextPaint;
    private float mTextWidth;
    private float mTextHeight;
    private ImageButton button_0, button_1, button_2, button_3, button_4, button_5, button_6;
    private ImageButton button_7, button_8, button_9, button_star, button_pound;
    private boolean clicked = false;
    private SparseIntArray drawables = new SparseIntArray();

    public DialView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public DialView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public DialView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        // Load attributes
        final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, R.styleable.DialView, defStyle, 0);

        mExampleString = a.getString(
                R.styleable.DialView_exampleString);
        mExampleColor = a.getColor(
                R.styleable.DialView_exampleColor,
                mExampleColor);
        // Use getDimensionPixelSize or getDimensionPixelOffset when dealing with
        // values that should fall on pixel boundaries.
        mExampleDimension = a.getDimension(
                R.styleable.DialView_exampleDimension,
                mExampleDimension);

        if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.DialView_exampleDrawable)) {
            mExampleDrawable = a.getDrawable(
                    R.styleable.DialView_exampleDrawable);
            mExampleDrawable.setCallback(this);
        }

        a.recycle();

        // Set up a default TextPaint object
        mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

        // Update TextPaint and text measurements from attributes
        invalidateTextPaintAndMeasurements();
    }

    private void invalidateTextPaintAndMeasurements() {
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(mExampleDimension);
        mTextPaint.setColor(mExampleColor);
        mTextWidth = mTextPaint.measureText(mExampleString);

        Paint.FontMetrics fontMetrics = mTextPaint.getFontMetrics();
        mTextHeight = fontMetrics.bottom;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

    public void getButtons(){}

    public void chooseButton(View v){}

    public void switchBackground(ImageButton button){}
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but if you want those `ImageButton`s to be added to your `CustomView`, then you would put them inside of `<CustomView>` tags, like you currently have it with the `<LinearLayout>`. You can then access them a few different ways; `findViewById()` in `onFinishInflate()`, overriding `addView(View, int, LayoutParams)` to get them as they're added, etc. You can also set the `OnClickListener` on each to call your `chooseButton()` method.

Comment: My apologizes for being unclear.
the two files doesnt seem to be linked because in the xml android:onClick="chooseButton" the IDE says: "cannot resolve symbol chooseButton"

Comment: You would remove those attributes. You're getting that error because that method doesn't exist in `DialView`, presumably. You can't use that attribute to set an `OnClickListener` target as anything other than an `Activity`. You would need to set the `OnClickListener` on each `ImageButton` yourself in code.